# Google login page - Sign in to continue to companyName

Tags: ios, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin, google-developers-console

I have modified the user agent to be able to login to Google. When the user tries to login, he sees the following screen:
[image]

The company name I hid is clickable. Upon clicking it, there pops a small dialogue box with some *Developer Info*.

1) Is there any way to disable that link?

2) If not, is it possible to modify the text inside the dialogue box? Because currently, personal email id of a developer is displayed which we don't want.

Any help or relevant link would be appreciated.

EDIT:
[image]

Just like **YouTube** is disabled, I want my company's name to be disabled as well..

Answer (score 2):

It seems that apart from YouTube no other company has this link disabled. I checked on MakeMyTrip, GoIbibo, TripAdvisor, StackOverflow and Quora. As YouTube is such a huge company, they might have got the screen customized from Google, just my hunch.[image]

[image]

Comment: Youtube is owned by Google itself!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- The best option is to create the project in a different Google account so your personal email won't show.
- In the Email field on API console "OAuth Consent screen", you can select the Google group email (so create a group).